# Lookup source filter in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am using lookup transformation in mapping.
In lookup, I am using lookup source filter and lookup sql override together.

But I have observed that only Lookup sql override is working. Condition in lookup source filter is not working when lookup sql override has some query in it. lookup source filter works when lookup sql override doesn't has any thing.
Can anyone please explain this behavior?

Thanx!

Answer (score 2):

This is the intended behaviour! If you are using sql override you would include the filter there only. Why do you need filter separately. Informatica cannot analyze and combine sql override and filter.

Answer (score 0):

Always override overrides filter condition in both LKP transformation and Source Qualifier transformation.